# Imessage delivery status

Tags: messages

When an imessage doesn't display delivered or not delivered beneath the message, will it update if and when the recipient is able to recieve iMessages again?

Answer (score 1):

If the message was **delivered**, whenever the recipient reads it, a **Read [Date]** will automatically be displayed beneath. Bear in mind, as Emil points out in the comments, that for this behaviour to happen, the receiver must have the **Send Read Receipts** option enabled.

If the message is marked as **not delivered**, it means that, for some reason, that message couldn't be sent. Although you *solve* the issue, it wont be automatically sent, therefore requiring you to tap on the *exclamation mark* and choosing **Try Again**.

Comment: That depends, if the reciever allows sending read-confirmations, it will display as _Read [date/time]_, but if it does not send read-confirmations, it will simply display _Delivered_.

Comment: @Emil True. I forgot about that. I'll edit my answer pointing that out.